# How to use scale with -moz-transform?

Tags: firefox, css, transform

Any body has a Good example showing how to use scale with [-moz-transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The MDC page you linked to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform#scale) actually explains it pretty well.

I made you a quick example. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SZ87b/1/ Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>-moz-transform scale example</title>
<style>
 p { font-size: 5em; text-align: center; }
 p:hover { -moz-transform: scale(2); }
</style>
<p>Foo bar</p>
```

Comment: dos the html5 doc type is must?

Comment: @Mithun: Nope, the HTML5 DOCTYPE is not required for this example to work. A browser that understands the proprietary `-moz-transform` CSS property is.

Comment: one problem you should be aware of, that FF is scaling from the middle, while all other browesrs using the 'zoom' css attribute scale from top-right.

Answer (score 9):

here is an example  of the css for the mayor browsers
The value scale(2,4) transforms the width to be twice its original size, and the height 4 times its original size.

```
div {
  transform: scale(2,4);
  -ms-transform: scale(2,4); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(2,4); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: scale(2,4); /* Opera */
  -moz-transform: scale(2,4); /* Firefox */
}
```

Comment: It is recommended to place the undisputed value last, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080674/1697459

Answer (score 3):

When using a scale (or rotate) transform you may need to set the origin.

```
  transform-origin: top left;
```

to get the effect you are looking for.