# Ordering of vendor-specific CSS declarations

Tags: css, vendor-prefix

I think I've written something like the following a thousand times now:

```
.foo {
    border-radius: 10px;         /* W3C */
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;    /* Mozilla */
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Webkit */
}
```

But only now have I thought about whether the ordering of those is important? I know that between `-moz-*` and `-webkit-*` it doesn't matter, since at most 1 of those will be read, but is it *better* (in terms of future-proofing, etc) to do the W3C standard first or last?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The best practise is undisputedly to have the unprefixed property last:

```
.foo {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;    /* Mozilla */
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Webkit */
    border-radius: 10px;         /* W3C */
}
```

Whichever is last out of `-webkit-border-radius` and `border-radius` will be the one that's used.

`-webkit-border-radius` is the "experimental" property - the implementation may contain deviations from the specification. The implementation for `border-radius` should match what's in the specification.

It's preferable to have the **W3C implementation** used when it's available, to help ensure consistency between all the browsers that support it.

Answer (score 20):

Ordering is important. To future proof your code you need to make the W3C spec come last, so the cascade favors it above the vendor prefixed versions.

```
.foo {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;    /* Mozilla */
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Webkit */
    border-radius: 10px;         /* W3C */
}
```

For example, lets say down the road Google Chrome supports the `border-radius`, but it also supports the `-webkit-border-radius` for backwards compatibility with its prior versions. When  Chrome encounters this `.foo` class now it will first see the -webkit, then it will see the standard, and it will default to the standard (and ignore webkit).