# Why is this css "transition" value an "invalid property value"

Tags: css, transition

I have the following CSS (and identical prefixed versions):

```
transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.4s ease-out,
            box-shadow         0.4s ease-out,
            -webkit-transform  0.4s ease-out,
            transform          0.4s ease-out,
            opacity            0.4s ease-out,
            -webkit-opacity    0.4s ease-out;
```

about which Chrome gives me this nonsense:

[image]

Hovering over the warning sign brings up a tooltip: "invalid property value".

I fail to see the difference to this (from [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/)):

> You may comma separate value sets to do different transitions on different properties:
>
> ```
> div {
>     transition: background 0.2s ease,
>                 padding 0.8s linear;
> }
> ```

Note that I cannot use `all`, because I am setting `.style` properties in JS which I don't want animated (unless there is a way to exclude `top` and `left` from the transition and still use `all`, which would be nice!).

How can I get my transition working again? Any advice appreciated.

---

**Edit:** Removing the prefixed ones didn't fix it, still an "Invalid property value" on transition and its prefixed forms.

**Edit 2:** I'm thoroughly confused. I've simplified it to this still-invalid code:

```
-webkit-transition: transform 0.4s ease-out, opacity 0.4s ease-out;
transition: transform 0.4s ease-out, opacity 0.4s ease-out;
```

**Edit 3:** Turns out the solution was just to update Chrome! I'd still like a workaround if possible.

Comment: My guess is that doesn't like the prefixes. You could try `transition: all .4s ease-out, top 0s, left 0s;`

Comment: To find out, try removing the properties with prefixes.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Unfortunately top and left are still animated with this. Same happens if I put top and left before transition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an invalid value property.

The [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transitions/#single-transition-property) says

> If one of the identifiers listed is not a recognized property name or
>   is not an animatable property, the implementation must still start
>   transitions on the animatable properties in the list using the
>   duration, delay, and timing function at their respective indices in
>   the lists for ‘transition-duration’, ‘transition-delay’, and
>   ‘transition-timing-function’. In other words, unrecognized or
>   non-animatable properties must be kept in the list to preserve the
>   matching of indices.

So even if you use vendor prefixes, it will still work.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is an answer and not a comment. Chrome is telling me it is an `invalid value property`, that's not just my opinion.

Comment: @JJ56 It's a bug. The [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transitions/#single-transition-property), the [validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) and Firefox's developer tools say it's a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be useful:

```
.className {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}
```

Comment: You should put the unprefixed property last, the prefixed ones first. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080605/ordering-of-vendor-specific-css-declarations

Answer (score 0):

Please check your CSS file for spelling mistakes.