# Center aligning Li's using text-align: center does not work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a bunch of li's with hyperlinks in them. Here's a demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOxJyr

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="categorycollapse">
    <ul id="Category" class="row list-inline  nav navbar-nav">      
        <li>
            <a href="/products/Category/Cars">
                Cars
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/products/Category/Cars%20R">
                Cars R
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/products/Category/Bus">
                Bus
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/products/Category/Bus">
                Bus
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/products/Category/Tempo">
                Tempo
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/products/Category/Cycle">
                Cycle
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/products/Category/Jet">
                Jet
            </a>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have used the following CSS for these list items to **center align them**. But it looks like some other css property is overriding my settings and the li's are left aligned instead. Check the bottom most row which is left-aligned.

```
#Category {
    border:1px solid #C4C6C6;
    margin: 0 60px 0 60px;
    padding: 20px !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}

#Category > li {
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}


#Category li a, ol li a {
 background-color: #07575B;
  color: #FFFFFF;
        transition: background .2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: background .2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: background .2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: background .2s ease-in;
        padding: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    display: inline !important;
}
```

How can I center align the list in a way that it overrides all css settings. With Center-align I mean if the elements span two rows, and the second row has only 3 elements, then those elements must be center-aligned and not left-aligned.

**Update:** Got it. The issue was with the attribute **navbar-nav** that I had applied on my Category which was left aligning the elements. I removed it.

Comment: I'm running your code above in Chrome. All `li`s are centered in the container. Is there another issue?

Comment: This is your exact code above: http://jsfiddle.net/xmd8bc68/ .. everything is centering

Comment: Increase the number of elements and it doesn't. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/xmd8bc68/1/

Comment: Here.. I built this recently for another answer... http://jsfiddle.net/du4nty1g/2/ ... useful?

Comment: Thanks Michael. I have solved it. Upvoting your comment since you too solved it.

Comment: Glad I could help. Also, as a side note, check the order of your `transition` declarations. It's generally better to put the W3C spec version last on the list. 
[Ordering of vendor-specific CSS declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080605/ordering-of-vendor-specific-css-declarations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried adding these **CSS** properties to your `UI` and it seemes to solve the issue;

```
#Category > ul {
  display:block;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

Checkout the link and let me know;

[Nav Aligned](https://jsfiddle.net/rxbLq91p/)

**Update:**

If you're looking forward to have your second row aligned at center, please remove `text-align:left !important` from your `#category` and add `text-align:center` instead, checkout this jsfiddle:

[Navs](https://jsfiddle.net/rxbLq91p/3/)

Comment: Thanks. I just checked and it doesn't. If you see the last row is still left-aligned. I have added some addtnl info.

Comment: you're looking forward to have the second row centered ?

Comment: Yes exactly and similarly any rows below it depending on the number of elements each row has

Comment: IWantToLearn, I've updated the answer, with the following css styling you can have as many as "li"'s you would like to have, displayed at center.

Comment: Got it. The issue was with the property  navbar-nav that I had applied on my Category. I removed it and everything works. I am marking your answer since it is technically correct.

Comment: Thank you, you can also use my css properties, but it's entirely up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Running OSX. Just checked your code in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Centered in each one. Are you, perhaps, using IE as your browser?