# How to write CSS correctly when there are the same properties but with different prefixes for the various browser support?

Tags: css, flexbox

If I have properties that are supported by browser with various prefixes, how I should to write the `CSS`?

Example:

```
#example {
    display: flex;  
    align-items: center;                    
    justify-content: space-around;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    display: -ms-flex;
    -ms-align-items:center;
    -ms-justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Or in this way ?

```
#example {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;          
    display: -ms-flex;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items:center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Or maybe there is not an order ?

Comment: Order doesn't matter, but you might be better off using SASS or LESS to auto generate the prefixes for you.

Comment: You have autoprefixers. You only write the standards, and it will rewrite for you all prefixes: https://www.google.es/search?q=css+autoprefixer  There are a lot of alternatives, even an online autoprefixer

Comment: Excuse my ignorance... but who rewrite my prefixes ? browser? is there a tool to generate prefixes?

Comment: @JosephGarrone: [Order certainly does matter.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080605/ordering-of-vendor-specific-css-declarations)

Comment: You don't really need to prefix everything. [This site](http://shouldiprefix.com/) contains a list of the prefixed and if you need them or not.

Comment: @BoltClock I was more implying the order of defining separate styles (IE: The justify, the align, the display).

Comment: @JosephGarrone: Fair enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use an online (or natively) tool that will automagically add the css prefixes for all browsers.

- http://pleeease.io/play/
- https://autoprefixer.github.io/

If you are using a build system like gulp or grunt, they have plugins that can automatically do this for you.

Comment: that tool suggest also to use "display: -webkit-box;" .... but this is an older syntax no ?

Comment: I don't know how you got "display: -webkit-box;"? I did not get that from both sites. I never used the online tools I only use gulp and I can recommend it.

Comment: i got it with second tool (autoprefixer)... maybe suggest older syntax?