# background videos shake on safari and firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser

I add some videos to my website and when I tested on Chrome it's working correctly, but when I tested on safari and Firefox it shakes. What is the problem?

This is my CSS code:

```
.parallax-background video {
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

When I read about this problem I think the problem in this part

```
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

But I don't know how I can fix it.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
.parallax-background video {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thank You but the video become small and its go to top and left

Comment: its work when i added to my code no replace, but he slow in safari and he display the alternative image then he load the video why ?

Comment: It's not possible to explain. I need to go through your css and js and explain for more. It the answer was correct upvote and click on the correct

Comment: The non-prefixed, standards compliant version [should _always_ come last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080605/ordering-of-vendor-specific-css-declarations/7080674).

Comment: @Turnip That's a new thing to me. Thank you